# Sharepoint 2007 and iOS 8 Devices

Tags: sharepoint-2007, ios8

I am working with a client who maintains their public facing websites with Sharepoint.  They are admittedly out of date and still using Sharepoint 2007 for the most part.

Example Page: http://www.kellerisd.net/Pages/default.aspx

With the recent release of iOS8 their website navigation is now broken in mobile safari and Chrome.  I have seen numerous posts regarding the changes to the JS engine for browsers with iOS8 (http://9to5mac.com/2014/06/03/ios-8-webkit-changes-finally-allow-all-apps-to-have-the-same-performance-as-safari/)but have no other means to explain the loss of functionality overnight.

I am working with them to update to SP 2013 which should alleviate the issue but I am looking to repair their site to keep them functional until the migration is possible.

Comment: See the [similar question over on Ask Different, Windows Authentication is broken in iOS 8, supposedly fixed in the 8.1 Beta](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146808/ios-8-safari-sharepoint-2013-windows-authentication-support).

Comment: That looks to be a great place to start.  Thank you

Comment: This has now been answered on Ask Different: [iOS 8 Safari ... Windows Authentication Support](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/146808/ios-8-safari-sharepoint-2013-windows-authentication-support). The iOS 8.1 update fixes the Windows Authentication bug.

Answer (score 0):

Don't expect SharePoint 2013 to help if they are using Windows Authentication... Windows Authentication is broken in iOS 8 Safari.  (Works OK in Chrome though.)

Comment: This should be in comment.

Comment: @SSA, this is an important point by mannaggia. If I recall correctly - SharePoint 2013 is the first release with official Microsoft support for the iOS Safari browser. See [Mobile ... browsers supported in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161353%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and [Mobile browsers ... supported in ... SharePoint Services 3.0 and in SharePoint Server 2007](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/930147).